# Posting audio files from Angular assets to server

Tags: javascript, angular, fileapi

I'm not able to create a proper File object like below. Its creating an File object with size 0.

```
const file = new File([''], '../../assets/' + filename);
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file, 'filename.wav');
this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/api', 
    formData ).subscribe(data => {
      console.log('success', data);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing the compile-time environment with the run-time environment. A web app running in a user's browser does not have access to your compile-time 'assets' directory.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek Yup, I missed that. Since the file in publically accessible. Can I build the file object from the url?

Comment: If your assets folder in inside your src folder (`src/assets/`) then you can use a route relative to the root of the url: `'/assets/' + filename`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a Blob first from the response of a XhrRequest, then converting it to a File object.

**sender.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class SenderService {
  postUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/post_url';
  fetchAudioUrl = 'http://localhost:4200/assets/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  send (audioFile: File) {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', audioFile, audioFile.name);
    return this.http.post(this.postUrl, formData);
  }

  getAudio (fileName: string) {
    return this.http.get(this.fetchAudioUrl + fileName, { responseType: 'blob'});
  }
}
```

**demo.component.ts**

```
import { SenderService } from './sender.service';

@Component({
......
  providers: [SenderService]
})
export class DemoComponent {

constructor(private senderService: SenderService) {}

  buttonClicked(req: any): void {
    this.senderService.getAudio(req.fileName)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        const file = new File([data], req.fileName);
        this.senderService.send(file)
          .subscribe((data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
          }, error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      });
  }
```

Comment: its better to use `switchMap` or `concatMap` instead of nested `subscribe`